# Getting how many pixels from the top a scrollbar is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I have a DIV element which ***width = 100%*** and ***height = 100%***

```
<div style='width:100%; height:100%'></div>
```

inside this DIV i have an iFrame where an external website is loaded which may be a random site with completely different domain.

I would like to know how can i find out how many pixels from the top the user has scrolled?

I tried almost everything but it seems not to work if the site that is loaded inside the iframe is hosted on another computer.

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing this, or what you are trying to achieve? There may be another way of doing it that you haven't considered.

Comment: the user need to be able to enter a website in an input field and this website to get loaded. Then an overlay is being placed over it which takes all the screen but the scrollbar so the user may be able to scroll down. Then he has to make selections over it which are rectangles and the coordinates need to be saved in a database